# How to Merge Data in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to combine some data in Excel, but I'm having trouble with some specifics. I have two columns named "User ID" that I want to merge, but one column has values the other doesn't. If a the two IDs match up, I want to have that whole row of data to line up. If one column has an ID the other doesn't, then I want the row to just have that User ID but leave the other fields blank.

For example. The user ID ADUBOSE appears in both User ID columns, so I want to line up that user's data across the board (userid, loginid, name and last login). However ABANKS only has a user ID in one column, so for that user I want the first two columns to line up (userid, loginid) and the rest to show blank/null. Hopefully that makes sense. Below is a screenshot of my file and one of how I'm wanting it to look.

[image: Excel File As Is]

[image: Excel File I Want]

Comment: Probably do, say, Remove Duplicates, then a `VLOOKUP()`?

Comment: I didn't come here for free code or to be berated. What I've tried is everything I know about Excel, plus an hour and a half of searching the net. I am not familiar with Excel code, so I haven't written any - I wouldn't know where to begin. I assumed there was formatting function, probably with a little bit of tweaking, that would get me to my solution, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm not familiar with the VLOOKUP() function, but from looking around on the net for a few, I'm not sure it's going to give me the result I'm looking for. It seems like it's only going to combine duplicate values, but not split the rows the way I'm looking for (refer to the second image as to what I'm looking for my result to be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `VLOOKUP` to merge the tables:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A28,$C$3:$E$10,1,0),"")`

What I am doing here is generating a relation between table 1 and table 2 using `userid` = `user ID`. The `VLOOKUP` function looks for a single value in `userid` `A28` that matches in the range `$C$3:$E$10` in `[column1]` column `C`, and once it get it, looks for the column number in the range that contains the return value.

If it doesn't find a match the function returns `N/A`. For avoid that I use `IFERROR`. This function evaluate the `VLOOKUP` and replace any `N/A` for an empty value `""` if that's the case.

`=VLOOKUP(Table3[userid],table2[range],column_number,False - exact match)`

If you want a detail definition check this links:

[Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) `VLOOKUP`

[Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) `IFERROR`

Also I recommend you to research about **Relational Databases** it will clarify your doubts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help virtualdvid, but this doesn't seem to show the result I am looking for (unless I'm misunderstanding how VLOOKUP works). In looking at my first screenshot, ABANKS appears in the first "userid" column, but not the second. So I would want the "User ID, Name and Last Login fields to be blank (or show null) in that row. ABIGGS would result in the same.

However ADUBOSE shows in the "userid" column as well as the User ID column, therefore I want a next row to be formatted showing  ADUBOSE's userid, loginid, User ID, Name and Last Login. It should show like the second screenshot

Comment: I'm not even sure if it's possible to do what I'm wanting, I just have a long list of data that needs to be formatted as such (like my second screenshot) and it would take a very long time to do it all manually. Surely there has to be a way to do it a little more quickly.

Comment: It will work the problem is how you organize your data. Looking in your first screenshot I see two tables. so you will need to create a third one where to merge those two tables. Let me work in a better example for my answer.

Comment: There we go! I updated my answer I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I'm trying to implement it now (while looking up some of those other things you shared). I'll see how it goes and let you know.

Comment: Awesome dude! Thank you so much for this. I didn't understand your formula very well at first, but the links to those articles you put in really helped me understand VLOOKUP. After playing with your formula for a while, I was able to get the data to read the way I wanted. I was afraid I was never going to understand this - LOL. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula to align duplicates values in two columns. If you use it on both sides, it return the desired result.

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$12,0)),"",INDEX($C$2:$C$12,MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$12,0)))

[image]

Comment: @Jeeped did the same thing to my question. His comments are rude and unnecessary and he should be blocked from commenting. If there's something wrong with the question, users should explain the issue instead of berating the person who posted. I hope my answer helps you TaRan.

Comment: I agree, Kay. There's no need for such comments here. Thank you for your answer. What Virtualdvid posted ended up giving me the results I was looking for. I'll look up the ISNA function you posted to learn more about it for future reference though.